# How to atomically check TWO AtomicBooleans in Java in one safe operation without a synchronized block (i.e. low cost locks)?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

So I have two AtomicBoolean and I need to check both of them. Something like that:

```
if (atomicBoolean1.get() == true && atomicBoolean2.get() == false) {

   // ...
}
```

But there is a race condition in between :(

Is there a way to combine two atomic boolean checks into a single one **without using synchronization** (i.e. synchronized blocks) ?

Comment: Synchronize around the critical sections.

Comment: I believe the answer is "no".  You could store the four possible combinations of states in an atomic integer, and access them atomically, but then I think you'd need a synchronized block to 'set' either of the booleans.

Comment: This is the best question that I've seen on Stack Overflow this month.

Comment: Reading is less of an issue than updating.  What are the legal value transitions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well I can think of a couple ways but it depends on the functionality you need.

One way is to "cheat" and use an [AtomicMarkableReference<Boolean>](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicMarkableReference.html):

```
final AtomicMarkableReference<Boolean> twoBooleans = (
    new AtomicMarkableReference<Boolean>(true, false)
);

void somewhere() {
    boolean b0;
    boolean[] b1 = new boolean[1];
    b0 = twoBooleans.get(b1);

    b0 = false;
    b1[0] = true;

    twoBooleans.set(b0, b1);
}
```

But that's kind of a pain and only gets you two values.

So then you can use AtomicInteger with [bit flags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_word):

```
static final int FLAG0 = 1;
static final int FLAG1 = 1 << 1;

final AtomicInteger intFlags = new AtomicInteger(FLAG0);

void somewhere() {
    int flags = intFlags.get();

    int both = FLAG0 | FLAG1;
    if((flags & both) == FLAG0) { // if FLAG0 has a 1 and FLAG1 has a 0
        something();
    }

    flags &= ~FLAG0; // set FLAG0 to 0 (false)
    flags |=  FLAG1; // set FLAG1 to 1 (true)

    intFlags.set(flags);
}
```

Also kind of a pain but it gets you 32 values. You could probably create a wrapper class around this if you really wanted. For example:

```
public class AtomicBooleanArray {
    private final AtomicInteger intFlags = new AtomicInteger();

    public void get(boolean[] arr) {
        int flags = intFlags.get();

        int f = 1;
        for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
            arr[i] = (flags & f) != 0;
            f <<= 1;
        }
    }

    public void set(boolean[] arr) {
        int flags = 0;

        int f = 1;
        for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
            if(arr[i]) {
                flags |= f;
            }
            f <<= 1;
        }

        intFlags.set(flags);
    }

    public boolean get(int index) {
        return (intFlags.get() & (1 << index)) != 0;
    }

    public void set(int index, boolean b) {
        int f = 1 << index;

        int current, updated;
        do {
            current = intFlags.get();
            updated = b ? (current | f) : (current & ~f);
        } while(!intFlags.compareAndSet(current, updated));
    }
}
```

That's pretty good. Maybe a set is performed while the array is being copied in get but the point is you can get *or* set all 32 atomically. (The compare and set do-while loop is major ugly but it's how the atomic classes themselves work for things like [getAndAdd](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.java#AtomicInteger.getAndAdd%28int%29).)

AtomicReference seems impractical here. It allows atomic gets and sets but once you have your hands on the internal object you are no longer updating atomically. You'd have to create a brand new object each time.

```
final AtomicReference<boolean[]> booleanRefs = (
    new AtomicReference<boolean[]>(new boolean[] { true, true })
);

void somewhere() {
    boolean[] refs = booleanRefs.get();

    refs[0] = false; // not atomic!!

    boolean[] copy = booleanRefs.get().clone(); // pretty safe
    copy[0] = false;
    booleanRefs.set(copy);
}
```

If you want to perform an interim operation on the data atomically (get -> change -> set, without interference) you have to use a lock or synchronization. Personally I would use a lock or synchronization since it's usually the case that the entire update is what you want to hold on to.

### ** UNSAFE !! **

Don't do this!

This can (possibly) be done with `sun.misc.Unsafe`. Here's a class that uses Unsafe to write to two halves of a volatile long, cowboy style.

```
public class UnsafeBooleanPair {
    private static final Unsafe UNSAFE;

    private static final long[] OFFS = new long[2];
    private static final long[] MASKS = new long[] {
        -1L >>> 32L, -1L << 32L
    };

    static {
        try {
            UNSAFE = getTheUnsafe();

            Field pair = UnsafeBooleanPair.class.getDeclaredField("pair");
            OFFS[0] = UNSAFE.objectFieldOffset(pair);
            OFFS[1] = OFFS[0] + 4L;

        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private volatile long pair;

    public void set(int ind, boolean val) {
        UNSAFE.putIntVolatile(this, OFFS[ind], val ? 1 : 0);
    }

    public boolean get(int ind) {
        return (pair & MASKS[ind]) != 0L;
    }

    public boolean[] get(boolean[] vals) {
        long p = pair;
        vals[0] = (p & MASKS[0]) != 0L;
        vals[1] = (p & MASKS[1]) != 0L;
        return vals;
    }

    private static Unsafe getTheUnsafe()
    throws Exception {
        Field theUnsafe = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
        theUnsafe.setAccessible(true);
        return (Unsafe)theUnsafe.get(null);
    }
}
```

Importantly, the [Javadoc in the Open JDK source](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/misc/Unsafe.java.html) for `fieldOffset` says *not* to do arithmetic with the offset. However, doing arithmetic with it appears to actually work in that I don't get garbage.

This nets a single volatile read for the entire word, but also (potentially) a volatile write to either half of it. Potentially `putByteVolatile` could be used to split a long in to 8 segments.

I wouldn't recommend that anybody use this (don't use this!) but it's kind of interesting as an oddity.

Comment: The problem is when you have to set just ONE boolean. Then you are in trouble, no? Let's say I want to set boolean 1 without caring for the value of boolean 0. Can I do that atomically? To say it differently, iI don't think you can set just ONE bit on an integer, atomically. :( :( :(

Comment: Yes, you must update them all at once. For your situation you should probably be using synchronization.

Comment: It would be nice some kind of checkAndAnd and checkAndOr methods, ah? :)

Comment: What do you mean? If you are asking for code I don't mind writing it though my answer is kind of long-winded already.

Comment: I don't think you can write it. If the AtomicInteger had checkAndAND or checkAndOR you would be able to set just one bit atomically. As it is now, you have to read it, AND and set again, two atomic operations.

Comment: Yeah, the atomics don't do that. The compound operations on atomics are implemented with [compare and swap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap) which is not a lock. Compare and swap just denies a write if there was interference. The write has to be reattempted until it succeeds. If failures are rare then it's faster than synchronization because the actual integer is just a volatile field. A few reattempts at a write might be faster than acquiring a monitor lock.

Comment: @JohnPristine, it is possible, same way `getAndAdd()` is implemented (in Java 7). Java 8 makes it easier by adding [`getAndUpdate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#getAndUpdate-java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator-).

Comment: @shmosel Been awhile since I looked at this Q&A, but yeah, that is a very handy method and probably makes this a bit simpler. It does the CAS from my `AtomicBooleanArray.set(int, boolean)` for us.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [Lock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html):

```
 Lock l = ...;
 l.lock();
 try {
     // access the resource protected by this lock
 } finally {
     l.unlock();
 }
```

it's technically not a synchronized block, even though it's a form of synchronization, i think that what you're asking for is the very definition of synchronization, so i don't think is possible doing it 'without synchronization'.

Answer (score 2):

I can only think of two ways: use the lower two bits of an `AtomicInteger` or use a spinlock. I think Hotspot can optimize certain locks down to spinlocks on its own.

Comment: With atomic integer you'd then have the same problem with atomically updating individual bits.

Comment: @trutheality You'd use a pattern like ```int a; do { a = b.get(); } while (!b.compareAndSet(a, a | 1);```