# How to use AtomicInteger with bit flags to atomically check two values in Java in one safe operation without a synchronized block?

Tags: java, multithreading, bit-manipulation, atomic

I saw that question: [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21925546/how-to-atomically-check-two-atomicbooleans-in-java-in-one-safe-operation-without)

Unfortunatelly I don't understand how to use AtomicInteger with bit flags to atomically check two values (as mentioned by @Radiodef in his answer) in Java.

Could somebody show me how to check atomically if for example:

```
((val1 == 1) && (val2 == 2)) == true
```

when val1 can be equal to 1 or 2 and val2 can be equal to 1, 2 or 3?

Comment: That answer is about two booleans (so bit flags can be used). It seems like you have 2 ints here? That answer is not applicable.

Comment: It it possible then to make atomic condition (if statement) evaluating 2 conditions? As in my question - I need to check if ((val1 == 1) && (val2 == 2)) == true atomically. @Sweeper

Comment: Those two variables have very limited set of possible values: 1 and 2 for the first one (val1), and 1, 2 and 3 for the second one (val2)

Comment: You use the first bit for val1 and the next two bits for val2.

Comment: @akuzminykh, ok. Great! I was hoping it was feasible. So I can then make those two conditions work atomic?

Comment: Yes, you have one atomic integer that's 32 or 8 bits wide.  You can atomically OR / AND / XOR, or compare_exchange, to change bits.  To check multiple bits, atomically read the whole int into a local temporary, then `tmp & mask == mask` to check that all bits in the mask were set.  Radiodef's answer shows an example of `if((flags & both) == FLAG0)` to check that FLAG1 was clear and FLAG0 was set.

Comment: @PeterCordes ok. Let's say that I want to operate on Boolians - is it possible to: {atomically change value of val1}, {atomically change val2} and {atomically compare if val1 == true && val2 == false}? I need those 3 things very much

Comment: Weird, Java AtomicInteger doesn't have `xorAndGet` or other bitwise ops, only `addAndGet`, at least in the Java 8 doc google found (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html).  But it has CAS as Radiodef's answer shows, and it has [`accumulateAndGet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#accumulateAndGet-int-java.util.function.IntBinaryOperator-) which you can use to apply any integer op you want, like `v.accumulateAndGet( 1<<3, xor_function)` to flip bit #4 (mask=1<<3).

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html seems to be the latest version, Java 21, and it still doesn't have atomic boolean ops on AtomicInteger, but does still have `accumulateAndGet`.  (Which is presumably just a wrapper for a CAS retry loop, unless it's smarter when compiling for some targets like x86 and can actually JIT to a `lock xor` or `lock and`.  Or `lock bts` to set a single bit and check the old value, like getAndOr with a 1-bit mask.)

Comment: @PeterCordes the performance of `getAndAccumulate` might be sufficient for a lot of use cases. If not, you have to resort to `VarHandle`.